# SOAP error when publishing Infopath 2010 form to Sharepoint

Tags: infopath, web-services, sharepoint-addin

I am working in a list which contains around 300 different fields.  I have also added another list as second data connection.     Everything is perfect at this stage and i am able to publish successfully.  After that i have given a action rule as Set Field Value to copy fields from the second data connection to Main data connection.   Now i am not able to save the form and publish the same.   I am getting "SOAP error when publishing Infopath form to Sharepoint" without any further description.    If i disable the rule, then its published successfully.  Since the above rule is necessary to copy data, i cannot disable the rule.    Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

300 Fields means you have created 300 columns in the Sharepoint list. That's pretty extreme for a sharepoint list. Especially since data will populate those fields. SOAP errors in infopath are generally a timeout with communicating between Infopath and the Sharepoint server, which means when you click publish it goes through each field in infopath and writes it in sharepoint. I have similar issues with a 250 field infopath form and I have begun to sacrifice lesser needed fields. If you have access to the farm you can try extending the timeout which I believe is defaulted at 5 minutes. Also from my experience Infopath takes especially long with calculated sharepoint fields, for me more than 3 is a deal breaker.

Comment: Researching the same thing a little more for my own issues, I came across several posts that pointed to one blog. It refers to changing the execution timeout. This was the exact issue we were dealing with. http://sharepointshah.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/soap-message-cannot-be-parsed-error.html

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem maybe, the "Main Connection" is a receive data connection and so you are not able to change the values of this data.

Though you can create data connections that submit data to a list which you could use, you would just need to create another data connection that submits data to the same list as the "Main Connection".

Hope this helps!